# thinking_sphinx not generating sphinx.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I've installed thinking_sphinx. I'm having trouble, any time I try and run `rake thinking_sphinx:index`  i get the error:

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name
```

The problem is... I can't for the life of me get the config/sphinx.yml file to generate. What should I do?

`gem list --local | grep thinking` returns `thinking-sphinx (2.0.10, 2.0.4)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `config/sphinx.yml` yourself - the format is much like config/database.yml, in that you group settings by environment.

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: what would my `searchd_binary_name` and `indexer_binary_name` be by default?

Comment: searchd and indexer, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but I have had the same problem and it was very silly. Although I had bundle installed ThinkingSphinx I never actually installed the sphinx itself.

If you run

```
which indexer
which searchd
```

and they don't return a path you don't have sphinx installed properly. If you do get a path and its different than /usr/local/bin modify your config/sphinx.yml accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I installed sphinx via homebrew on Lion and the path needed for bin_path was

/Users/username/.homebrew/Cellar/sphinx.2.0.7/bin